# C++ start a script ( bash, python ... ) and using stdin/stdout for datatransfare [linux]

Tags: python, c++, linux, stdout, stdin

I want to call a python script from my C++ code. The python script looks like:

```
    hello.py
    #!/usr/bin/python
    import sys
    print "Hello!"
    Readin = sys.stdin.read()
    print Readin
```

The C++ code is from a other question from stack overflow. How it should work:

- Creating a pair of pipes.
- Creating a child process with `fork()`.
- **child** is bending its pipes to stdin / stdout. Closing the other ends
  and starting the script.
- **father** is listening on the pipes `read()`, receiving input. And after it,
  sending a Message  `write()`.

The program does not return from **fathers** line, when `switch (readResult = read(childToPa...` is entered.

I'm also do not know if this writing part is doing its job. Is this a promising idea to do that like this, or are there other working possibilities?
thx!

It looks like:

```
// maybe not all includes are necessary
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> // mkdir
#include <stdlib.h>     // system()
#include <unistd.h> // rmdir
#include <cstring> // memset

// wait:
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  char target[] = "./hello.py";

  enum PIPE_FILE_DESCRIPTERS {
    READ_FD = 0, WRITE_FD = 1
  };

  enum CONSTANTS {
    BUFFER_SIZE = 100
  };

  int parentToChild[2];
  int childToParent[2];
  pid_t pid;
  string dataReadFromChild;
  char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE + 1];
  memset(buffer,0x00,BUFFER_SIZE + 1);
  ssize_t readResult;
  int status;

  int retPipe1 =  pipe(parentToChild);
  int retPipe2 =  pipe(childToParent);

  switch (pid = fork()) {
  case -1:
    printf("Fork failed");
    exit(-1);

  case 0: /* Child will start scripts*/ 
  {
    // Bending stdin/out to the pipes?
    int retdup21 = dup2(parentToChild[READ_FD], STDIN_FILENO);
    int retdup22 = dup2(childToParent[WRITE_FD], STDOUT_FILENO);
    int retdup23 = dup2(childToParent[WRITE_FD], STDERR_FILENO);
    // Close in this Process the other sides of the pipe
    int retclose1 = close(parentToChild[WRITE_FD]);
    int retclose2 = close(childToParent[READ_FD]);

    int retexe = execlp( target ," ");              // warning not enough variable arguments to fit a sentinel [-Wformat=]

    printf("This line should never be reached!!!"); // why? what happens if execlp finishes?
    exit(-1);
    break;  // to make the compiler happy =)
  }
  default: /* Parent */
    cout << "Child " << pid << " process running..." << endl;

    // close the other ends of the pipe from the other process.
    int retdup21 = close(parentToChild[READ_FD]);
    int retdup22 = close(childToParent[WRITE_FD]);

    // readtry
    while (true) {
      switch (readResult = read(childToParent[READ_FD], buffer, 1)) // execution does not return from this function.
      {
      case 0: /* End-of-File, or non-blocking read. */
      {
        cout << "End of file reached..." << endl << "Data received was (" << dataReadFromChild.size() << "):" << endl
            << dataReadFromChild << endl;

        cout << "starting writing" << endl;
        char bufferW[] = "{\"AElement\":\"Something\"}\0";


               int writeResult = write(parentToChild[WRITE_FD],bufferW,sizeof(bufferW));
               int saveerrno = errno;

               if( -1 == writeResult)
               {
                 cout << "errno while writing: " << errno << std::endl;
                 if ( 9 == saveerrno )
                   cout << "Errno Bad File descriptor" << endl;
               }

               cout << "Write Result: " << writeResult << std::endl;

        int retWait = waitpid(pid, &status, 0);

        cout << endl << "Child exit staus is:  " << WEXITSTATUS(status) << endl << endl;

        exit(0);
      }
      case -1:
      {
        if ((errno == EINTR) || (errno == EAGAIN)) {
          errno = 0;
          break;
        } else {
          printf("read() failed");
          exit(-1);
        }
      }
      default:
        dataReadFromChild.append(buffer, readResult);
        printf("%s",buffer);
        memset(buffer,0x00,BUFFER_SIZE + 1);
        break;
      }
    } /* while ( true ) */
  } /* switch ( pid = fork() )*/
}
```

Comment: Firstly, how is it relevant that you run Python code inside the other program? Answer: It's not. So, you could easily reduce your code and question, getting closer to a minimal example. However, even then, I wonder where you got the idea for the approach from? It's not new, not unique and actually well established. So, it should be trivial to locate existing, working examples!

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt The assembly has a c++ core. This is getting an input for a job. The core is preparing this job, updating database etc. After this the job will be done by python. The core will remain for future. But the kind of jobs to do will change in the future. So we searched for a easy way doing this. Input Scriptfile name with API -> C++ preparing -> Python doing. Is there a better way to perfom this? I'm a c programmer, and I do not prefer to use this hack. Because those scripts should be possible to be called by each other, the stdin/put way was suggested. Better Ideas? Thx =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems are buffered output, unclosed file descriptors and using EOF to signal the end of a *part* of the transmission. The first two problems can be solved, but the last one needs a different approach. More on that later.

Step by step:

Python is using buffered I/O, so you may want to force Python to flush the output by adding a line `sys.stdout.flush()` after the first print statement. Now `"Hello!\n"` is read character by character.

But then the next `read` blocks until a new character arrives or the pipe is closed. STDOUT of the Python script is still open, the C++ program is waiting for something to arrive, but the Python script itself is waiting for some input, too. Classic deadlock.

You might discard the last print in the python script and try to close its STDOUT. Since `read` blocks until all file descriptors referencing the writing end of the pipe are closed, you will have to add `os.close(sys.stdout.fileno())` and `os.close(sys.stdout.fileno())` after the `flush`.

But there are still valid filedescriptors referencing the write part of that pipe. Remember the `dup2` in the C++ source? After these three `dup2` lines there are still `parentToChild[READ_FD]` and `childToParent[WRITE_FD]` referencing the scripts STDIN and STDOUT. So we have to close them. Add `close(parentToChild[READ_FD]);` and `close(childToParent[WRITE_FD]);` right after the `dup2`s. Now `read` returns `0` when Python script closes STDOUT and STDERR.

Next, the parent sends `"{\"AElement\":\"Something\"}\0"` and reaches `waitpid` which returns when the child exits. But the child is still reading from STDIN. So you have to add `close(parentToChild[WRITE_FD]);` before `waitpid`.

---

Now for the conceptual part: You can't `read()` until it returns a `0` (pipe closed), and then continue to read from that closed pipe. Your choices:

- Read once until the pipe is closed. No second message possible.
- Know how much to read. Either in advance or by interpreting the received bytes.
- Monitor both pipes e.g. with [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) and decide dynamically if you want to read or write.

BTW: The arguments of `execlp` are `const char *file, const char *arg, ...`, where `arg, ...` are the usual `char *args[]` starting with `arg[0]`(!) and ending with a null pointer. Please change that line to `int retexe = execlp(target, target, (char*) NULL);`

---

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import os
import sys

print "Hello!"
sys.stdout.flush()
os.close(sys.stdout.fileno())
os.close(sys.stderr.fileno())

data = sys.stdin.read()
with open("data_received_by_child.txt", "w") as fp:
    print >>fp, data
```

---

```
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char *target = "./hello.py";

    enum PIPE_FILE_DESCRIPTERS {
        READ_FD = 0, WRITE_FD = 1
    };

    /* Make pipes */
    int parentToChild[2]; /* Parent to child pipe */
    if (pipe(parentToChild) < 0)
    {
        perror("Can't make pipe");
        exit(1);
    }
    int childToParent[2]; /* Child to parent pipe */
    if (pipe(childToParent) < 0)
    {
        perror("Can't make pipe");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Create a child to run command. */
    pid_t pid = fork();
    switch (pid)
    {
        case -1:
            perror("Can't fork");
            exit(1);

        case 0: /* Child */
            close(parentToChild[WRITE_FD]);
            close(childToParent[READ_FD]);
            dup2(parentToChild[READ_FD], STDIN_FILENO);
            dup2(childToParent[WRITE_FD], STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(parentToChild[READ_FD]);
            close(childToParent[WRITE_FD]);
            execlp(target, target, (char *) NULL);
            perror("Can't execute target");
            exit(1);

        default: /* Parent */
            close(parentToChild[READ_FD]);
            close(childToParent[WRITE_FD]);
            cout << "Child " << pid << " process running..." << endl;
    }

    /* Read data from child */
    string dataReadFromChild;
    char ch;
    int rc;
    while ((rc = read(childToParent[READ_FD], &ch, 1)) != 0)
    {
        if (rc == -1) {
            if ((errno == EINTR) || (errno == EAGAIN)) {
                continue;
            }
            perror("read() failed");
            exit(-1);
        }
        dataReadFromChild += ch;
    }
    close(childToParent[READ_FD]);
    cout << "End of file reached..." << endl;
    cout << "Data received was (" << dataReadFromChild.size() << "):" << endl;
    cout << dataReadFromChild << endl;

    /* Write data to child */
    cout << "starting writing" << endl;
    const char bufferW[] = "{\"AElement\":\"Something\"}\0";
    while (true) {
        int rc = write(parentToChild[WRITE_FD], bufferW, sizeof(bufferW));
        if (rc == -1) {
            if ((errno == EINTR) || (errno == EAGAIN)) {
                continue;
            }
            perror("write() failed");
            exit(-1);
        }
        break;
    }
    close(parentToChild[WRITE_FD]);

    /* Wait for child to exit */
    int status;
    int retWait = waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    cout << endl << "Child exit status is:  " << WEXITSTATUS(status) << endl << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for those lot of informations and pointing out every error I did/copied. I'll work at those in a couple of days. To get more informations abut this topic. Programm communication stuff, pipes, starting external programs and zombies. Can you give me the name of a good book, or some keywords, where to start my search?

Comment: The best book on POSIX level and Linux programming that I've come across is "The Linux Programming Interface" by Michael Kerrisk. I also liked the "POSIX Programmer’s Guide" by Donald Lewine (published in 1991, now available for free). But my most important reference are the man pages.

Comment: **Thank You!** For first iteration into the topic i like to have books. Than you can enjoy the man-pages for futher questions.

Comment: "The Linux Programming Interface" is awesome. Detailed chapters. everything explained from the beginning. Thx again.